# Is it possible to estimate $\mathbf{A}$ in $\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{b}$ based on initial guess

Tags: linear-algebra, parameter-estimation

I am trying to solve $\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{b}$, but this time $\mathbf{A}$ is unknown. I do, however, have a pretty good starting guess for $\mathbf{A}$, but it needs some slight modifications. I know the problem is very underdetermined, but is there a way/method of estimating $\mathbf{A}$ based on the initial guess? $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ contain noise, so an exact solution does not exist.

Even just some keywords to help me in my further search would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If $\hat A$ is your initial guess, you could choose $A$ to minimize $\| Ax - b \|^2 + \gamma \| A - \hat A \|^2$, where $\gamma > 0$ is a parameter whose value you can tune by trial and error. It is possible to find an analytical solution to this optimization problem.